# Redux Persist and Update Packager in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

hy, i have a problems when i'm updating packager in react native, my data that has been saved in my local storage (redux-persist) is gone or back to Initial_State, but this is just happen in apk release, when i try to update in apk debug, there is no problem with data in local storage.

can anyone explaine what is wrong in this problem?
packager what i update is :

1. react-navigation = from 1.0.0-beta.21 to ^2.11.2
2. redux-persist = from ^4.9.1 to ^5.10.0
3. and add packager react-navigation-redux-helpers to help react-navigation in redux